# AngularJS Form Unit Testing Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to set up a unit test for my form processing controller, but I'm seemingly having issues with setting it up properly.

Here is my code for the controller to process a form:

```
app.controller("FormController", ['$scope', '$http', '$window',  function($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.message = "";

    $scope.processForm = function() {
     $scope.message = "Processing form";
     $scope.messageStyle = {
     "color": "green"
     };

     $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/register',
        data:{
          "username": $scope.user.username,
          "email": $scope.user.email,
          "password": $scope.user.password,
          "confirm": $scope.user.confirm
        }
      }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.message = data.msg;

        if (data.success) {
          $window.location.href = "/confirm";
        } else {
          $scope.messageStyle = {
            "color": "red"
          };
        }

      });

    };
   }]);
```

Here's my unit testing code using Mocha and Chai:

```
describe("FormController", function(){

  var scope;
  var ctrl;
  var httpBackend;
  var http;

   beforeEach(module("home"));

   beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, $http) {

     scope = $rootScope.$new();
     http = $http;
     ctrl = $controller("FormController", {$scope : scope, $http : http});
     httpBackend = $httpBackend;
   }));

  describe("when calling the processForm function", function(){

  beforeEach(function() {
       scope.processForm();

    });

    it("Should contain a message", function(){
      expect(scope.message).to.equal("Processing form");
    });

   });

});
```

When I run the test, I get back the following error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.user.username')`

How should I solve this issue?

Comment: Why are you stringify-ing your POST data and adding the content-type header? Angular's `$http` does all that for you

Comment: Also, you obviously need to create a `user` object on your scope before calling `processForm`

Comment: @Phil I have updated my code to reflect the POST data changes. My `user` is coming from the ng-model. So I have something like `ng-model="user.username"` in the html form.

Comment: A controller test does not include any templates so you'll have to manually set up model data before calling `processForm()`

Comment: @Phil Could you give me an example on how to do this?

Comment: Before you call `scope.processForm()` in your test, add `scope.user = {username: 'foo', email: 'foo@example.com', ...}`. Of course, you'll also have to add the expected HTTP calls to `httpBackend`

Answer (score 0):

try following code in before each

```
 beforeEach(function() {
   elm = angular.element(
       '<form ng-controller="FormController">' +
    '<input ng-model="user.username">' +
         '<input ng-model="user.email">' +
         '<input mg-model="user.password">' +
         '<input mg-model="user.confirm">' +
        '</form>');
     scope = $rootScope;
     $compile(elm)(scope);
     scope.$digest();
        scope.processForm();

 });
```

Hope this will help you